# Adding Redux-Toolkit to Next.js project within Nx Monorepo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nrwl-nx

I was wondering if there is a way to add Redux-Toolkit to a Next.js project within a Nx Monorepo. I was able to find some guidance for a React project [link](https://nx.dev/latest/react/react/redux). It does not look like it works with the Next.js. Let me know if there is any guidance on it.

Comment: Would also love to have this

Comment: Hey in what way does it not work? Just tried it, threw an error about main.tsx but added that, and slice generation works fine.